# glclampcolor missing in QT

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm working on a Render to Texture in QT with QGLWidget and a QGLFramebufferObject.
My intention is to write floating point values to the texture via  a shader.

I use a GL_RGB32F texture and the RTT seems to be happening. However, the values stored in the texture seem to be clamped between 0 and 1.

A test value of gl_FragData[0] = vec4(120.0, 2.0, 0.8, 1.0); in the shader
results in 1.0, 1.0, 0.8 in the texture.

I see posts that suggest that calls to glClampColor

glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_FALSE);

will get rid of this clamping, but unfortunately I'm not able to find this call in QT 5.0.2. It seems to be removed after QT 4.3 inside QOpenGLFunctions

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `QOpenGLFunctions` class is designed to provide access to the OpenGL/ES 2.0 API, which doesn't define `glClampColor`.  You could try upgrading to Qt 5.1, which provides a `QOpenGLFunctions` class for every OpenGL version (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/classes.html#o).

Comment: what about clamping? http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Floating_point_and_mipmapping_and_filtering says GL_TGB32F should not clamp color?

Answer (score 0):

Use QT with OpenGL Desktop version like here
[Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 504 MB)](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2010_opengl-x86-offline.exe)

more about OpenGL and QT:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL

As you see by default OpenGL ES 2.0 version (through Angle project) is used and glClampColor is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your reply. Migrating to 5.1 seemed more time consuming, so I ended up using glGetTexImage to copy the whole texture and read the required texel. It is slower compared to a glReadPixels implementation, but works as of now. When I have the time to upgrade, these suggestions would definitely be of great use.

Thanks again!